# Creating a .p file from an InvertedIndex

Tags: indexing

I am trying to construct a Python search engine that will pull queried tweets out of the TwitterAPI.  **I cannot use tweepy**.    I have constructed the class TwitterWrapper, class Engine, and have also created the (pickled) corpus from my query term of “raptor”, no problem there.  I have created the class InvertedIndex but cannot seem to construct the index of lemmatized words and add it to my Jupyter Notebooks as a pickle file (.p) (which I must do) in order to use my TwittIR.py interface:

```
t = TwittIR.Engine(“raptor.p”, “index (to be named).p”)
results = t.query (“raptor”)
for result in results:
   print(result)
```

So, my question is, how do I make an index (using my inverted index), and save it into my Jupyter Notebook as a .p file?  I am of course, somewhat of a Python beginner.

```
def build_index(self, corpus):
    index = {}
    if self.lemmatizer == None:
        self.lemmatizer = nltk.WordNetLemmatizer()
    if self.stop_words is None:
        self.stop_words = [self.wordtotoken(word) for word in 
        nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')]
    for doc in corpus:
        self.add_document(doc['text'], self.ndocs)
        self.ndocs = self.ndocs + 1


def __getitem__(self,index):
    return self.index[self.normalize_document(index)[0]]
```